# Bnot Yisrael instead of Bnot Yerushalayim

Tags: masechet-taanis

On the last amud of Taanis, when quoting the Mishnah to start a new sugya, the Gemara says בנות ישראל (talking about the women going to the fields on Tu B’av), but the Mishnah’s wording was בנות ירושלים. Why the switch?

Answer (score 1):

There are indeed different girsaos there. See [Dikdukei Sofrim](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=38514#p=172) (and from there in Shinuyei Nuschaos printed at the side of the Yachin Uboaz Mishnayos). The copyists and/or printers weren't always consistent in which manuscripts they copied from.